# Expected identifier or '(' in yacc

Tags: token, yacc, unexpected-token

Expected identifier or '(' in the first % ,
I have no clue why this is an error , I am new coding for yacc.
I have checked multipule times the syntax but didn't find anything.

```
%{
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include "global.h"

extern int line_number;

int yylex(void);
void yyerror(char *s);

node * root;
%}
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/q/41315168/5468463 ?

Comment: For me, this gives `file.y:13.1: error: syntax error, unexpected end of file` which seems perfectly reasonable and expected.  What were you expecting?